# "Тапочка" или "тапочек"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Какое единственное число от слова "тапочки": "тапочка" или "тапочек"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По словарю Ушакова - "тапочка".

Answer (score 2):

И впрямь *тапочка*, нам повезло, совпадение в нашу пользу. Почему повезло, спросите вы? Господа, паки и паки повторяю: за нормами современного русского языка **нельзя** обращаться к словарям, изданным до действующих «Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 г. Норма, приводимая в них, может оставаться неизменной и в наши дни, а может (в весьма значительном числе случаев) быть давно и безнадёжно устаревшей. Иными словами, в конкретном случае мы не можем быть уверены, что рекомендация словаря Ушакова сегодня не стала ошибочной. Это не занудство, поверьте. Это вещь, без объяснений понятная любому хорошему филологу, но отчего-то неясная большинству людей (ещё и к Далю за орфографическими нормами обращаются!..).

Answer (score 0):

Да, тапочка. Но многие до сих пор считают, что это тапок.

Answer (score 0):

Если уж на то пошло, то *тапка*. Тапочка - это уже диминутив.

Но это ещё цветочки. Ягодки у Кузнецова:

*ТАПКИ, -пок, -пкам; мн. (ед. тапка, -и; ж. и **тапок, -а; м.**).
Мягкие лёгкие туфли без каблуков. Спортивные, домашние т. Больничные т. Парусиновые, кожаные т. Т. на войлочной, резиновой подошве. Переобуться в т. Положить в т. стельки. < Тапочки, -чек, -чкам; мн. (ед. тапочка, -и; ж. и **тапочек, -а; м.**). Разг.*

Так что смелее в бой с тапком наперевес.